# Variational Problem on a manifold - bounding my functional from below

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, functional-inequalities

Let $(M, g_{ij})$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. Let $f \in C^{0,\alpha}(M)$ be a given function.  I have the linear operator $L = \Delta h - 12u^2h$, where $u \in C^{2,\alpha}$.  I need to show that $L$ is onto; i.e., I need to show that $\forall f \in C^{0,\alpha}$, $\exists h \in C^{2,\alpha}$ such that $Lh=f$.

The only method I have at my disposal for solving $Lh=f$ is the variational method.  So, what I need to do first is show that my functional $I(h)=\int \left( \Delta h - 12u^2h^2-fh\right)$ is bounded from below.  Since I'm on a compact manifold, I do not have compact support, and thus cannot do this the way I would normally have done it, which would have been the following:

$I(h) = \int\left ( \Delta h - 12u^2h^2-fh\right) = ||Dh||_{L^{2}}^{2} - \int(-12u^{2})(h^{2})-\int fh = ||Dh||_{L^2}^{2} - ||12u||_{L^{2}}^{2}||h||_{L^{2}}^{2}-||f||_{L^{2}}||h||_{L^{2}}^{2} \geq ||Dh||_{L^{2}}^{2} - \left( \frac{\epsilon}{2}||h||_{L^{2}}^{2}+\frac{1}{2\epsilon}||12u||_{L^2}^{2}\right) - \left( \frac{\epsilon}{2}||h||_{L^{2}}^{2}+\frac{1}{2\epsilon}||f||^{2}_{L^{2}}\right) = ||Dh||_{L^{2}}^{2}-\epsilon ||h||_{L^{2}}^{2} - \frac{1}{2\epsilon}\left(||12u||^{2}_{L^{2}} + ||f||_{L^{2}}^{2}\right)$.

Then, since $h$ is the quantity that varies, the only way that $I(h)$ can be bounded from below is for it to be positive, so we need to have $||Dh||_{L^{2}}^{2} \geq \epsilon ||h||_{L^{2}}^{2}$, which is guaranteed by the Poincare Inequality, so $I(h) \geq ||Dh||_{L^{2}}^{2} \geq \epsilon ||h||_{L^{2}}^{2}$, and thus $I(h)$ is bounded below.

But, I cannot use this.  In order to use the Poincare Inequality in the space I am in, where I do not have compact support, I need to have $||Dh||_{L^{2}}^{2} \geq \epsilon ||h - \overline{h}||_{L^{2}}^{2}$, where $\overline{h}$ is the average value of the function $h$.  However, I don't know at all how to fit this in with what I've done above. Please help!

Comment: Your functional ought to be $I(f) = \int_M \left(\frac{1}{2}|\nabla h|^2 + 6 u^2 h^2 - hf \right) dx$. However this is not bounded from below without additional assumptions on $u$ and/or $M$. For example, if $u \equiv 0$ on a connected component $M_1$ of $M$, this is not bounded from below. Just choose $h = c$ on $M_1$ and $h = 0$ elsewhere, where $|c|$ is large.

Comment: So, if u is not identically zero, though, can I use the regular Poincare inequality, etc, to show what I want to show?

Comment: If $M$ is compact, then you obviously have compact support. Then the Poincaré inequality is indeed true in the form in which you stated it.

Comment: So, all I need to do is make the changes that you suggested, and I'm good to go?

Comment: @HansEngler, I think it should be $-6u^{2}h^{2}$ in the functional, right?

Comment: The Euler-Lagrange equation for the functional with $+6u^2h^2$ is $\int_M \left( \nabla h \cdot \nabla v + 12 u^2 h v - f v \right) = 0 for all test functions $v$, which becomes $\int_M \left( - \Delta  h \cdot v + 12 u^2 h v - f v \right) = 0$. So the sign should be $+6 u^2 h^2$.

Comment: As to "good to go": With this approach you will only be able to show that there is a unique $H^1(M)$ minimizer. You then have to show it is in $C^{2,\alpha}(M)$ which requires standard regularity theory. Check out Gilbarg-Trudinger.

Comment: @HansEngler, I got back that the Euler-Lagrange equation for this functional is $\Delta h - 12u^{2}h+f$, not $-f$.

Comment: OK, so switch the sign.

Comment: I did,and it all worked out great! Thank you so much for your help!! :)